# Display product base image in .phtml template file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, template, phtml

**SOLVED** (See my answer below)

---

How can I display product base image in .phtml template file?

```
$relatedProducts = $product->getProduct()
        ->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(['price','name','image','status']);
```

Can I put addAttributeToSelect to use for this?

I found this in one other post, but it doesn't work (I put it in Block/Product.php and called it in view/frontend/templates/related_products.phtml , the getImage() part doesn't get added to URL):

```
public function getProductImageUrl()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()
        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $this->getImage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public function getProductImageUrl($product)
{
    return $this->_image->init($product, 'product_base_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)
                ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                ->getUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your block:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Newproducts extends Template
{
    private $_productFactory;

    public function __construct
    (
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        array $data
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function getProductRelated($prodId)
    {
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
        $product->load($prodId);

        $collection = $product
            ->getRelatedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['price','name','image','status']);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

and then call block method in your template phtml:

```
<ul>
        <?php foreach ($block->getProductRelated($prodID) as $product): ?>
                <li><?php echo $product->getImage() ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: where to create this block ?

Answer (score 0):

Get product image from Product in PHTML file for Magento 2

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imageHelper  = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
<?php $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl(); ?>
```